# What is the Fourier transform of the logarithm of error and complementary error function

Tags: integration

Can anyone help me with the Fourier transform
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i \omega x} \ln(f(x)) dx$, with $f(x) = \mathrm{erfc}(x)$ or $\mathrm{erf}(x)$? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

one way you could try is IBP:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\omega x}\ln(\operatorname{erf}(x))dx=\left[\frac{e^{-i\omega x}}{-i\omega}\ln(\operatorname{erf}(x))\right]_{x=-\infty}^\infty-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\omega x}\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\operatorname{erf}(x)}dx$$
and see if you can go anywhere from here?

Comment: But the problem is what's the Fourier transform of $$\frac{-2e^{-x^2}/\sqrt{\pi}}{\mathrm{erfc}(x)}$$?